# What is the difference between "Bay" and "Stand"?

Tags: air-traffic-control, ground-operations, taxiing

When should we use the word **Stand** and when **Bay** for ATC taxi clearance?

Comment: Do you have any example where you heard such word (I never heard "bay" neither read it in a transcript, but I'm not an aviation professional)?

Answer (score 1):

The correct terminology for a place where aircraft park is **stand** or **aircraft stand**, where **bay** or **parking bay** is colloquial.

The official definition from the [ICAO ANNEX 14/I Aerodromes](https://www.bazl.admin.ch/dam/bazl/de/dokumente/Fachleute/Regulationen_und_Grundlagen/icao-annex/icao_annex_14_aerodromesvolumei-aerodromedesignandoperations.pdf.download.pdf/an14_v1_cons.pdf) is:

> ***Aircraft stand.*** A designated area on an apron intended to be used for parking an aircraft.

This can be either a stand at a gate or a remote parking stand.

The correct use of the word **bay** is for a **holding bay** as defined in [ICAO ANNEX 14/I Aerodromes](https://www.bazl.admin.ch/dam/bazl/de/dokumente/Fachleute/Regulationen_und_Grundlagen/icao-annex/icao_annex_14_aerodromesvolumei-aerodromedesignandoperations.pdf.download.pdf/an14_v1_cons.pdf) as:

> ***Holding bay.*** A defined area where aircraft can be held, or bypassed, to facilitate efficient surface movement of aircraft.

So you use the term **stand** for an area where aircraft park (i.e. shut down engines, load/unload cargo, (dis-)embark passengers, etc.) and you use the term **bay** for an area where an aircraft temporarily holds (typically with engines running).

---

There are some sources using the term **bay** for parking, but I would consider all of them more informal than the official ICAO definitions:

- The [ENAV](https://www.enav.it/sites/public/en/Servizi/Air-Traffic-Handling.html) (company providing air traffic control services in Italy) writes (emphasis mine):

  > [...] which guides it right up to the **parking bay**.

  on the English version of their website, but this could also be a wrong translation from the Italian original.
- The [Thales Group](https://www.thalesgroup.com/en/global/activities/aerospace/air-traffic-management/automation) (French aerospace company) writes (emphasis mine):

  > Tower ensures smooth and seamless aircraft control between TMA boundary and the **parking bay**.

  which again might be result of incorrect terminology used by the translator.
- This [article by Qantas](https://www.qantasnewsroom.com.au/roo-tales/can-you-speak-aviationese/) suggests that the term is actually used by Australian ATCs (emphasis mine):

  > PILOT: “Qantas 635...we will arrive on blocks at 1500. Have 2 UMs, 2 WCHRs, 1 will need assistance to a taxi. Request a **parking bay** please.”
  >
  > MOCO: “Copy that Qantas 635. 2 UMs, 2 WCHRs. You are for **parking bay** 26...2...6. See you on the ground Qantas MEL.
- The [CAAS](https://www.caas.gov.sg/about-caas/newsroom/Detail/caas-contributes-to-efforts-to-reduce-aircraft-fuel-consumption-and-carbon-emissions/) (Civil Aviation Authority of Singapore) is also using the term (emphasis mine):

  > the aircraft was also assigned the shortest possible route from the runway to the **parking bay** to minimise fuel consumption.

---

Related:

- [What is the difference between a Stand and Gate in Airports? How do they differ ?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/50009/what-is-the-difference-between-a-stand-and-gate-in-airports-how-do-they-differ)
- [What are the correct names of the parking spaces for turn-around?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/30638/what-are-the-correct-names-of-the-parking-spaces-for-turn-around/30640#30640)